# Insufficient privileges when creating a Azure pipeline in my own project

Tags: python, azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I am currently trying to create a pipeline for my python flask webapp in Azure DevOps for a university project.
I have the student subscription and added my code to the repo.

When trying to create a pipeline, I choose the Azure Repo git, select my repo and choose "Python to Linux Web App on Azure". After choosing my subscription and clicking on "Validate and configure" I get the following error:

[image: Picture of the error]

I can't find any setting related to this problem. Especially because I am the owner of the organisation and project, I have all the permissions to do everything (at least with the settings available in Azure DevOps).

Maybe someone knows a solution to this problem. Sadly I couldn't find one on the internet yet.

Greetings,
Lukas

Comment: Something seems misconfigured as the error indicates that your user does not have permissions to create an Azure AD app. Have you selected as the source of your code your Azure Repos repositoy?

Comment: @GeralexGR Yeah, I did. I uploaded my local copy of the project into the Azure devops repo and later chose it for the pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You need at least Application Administrator role in Azure AD. You should have this as you've created the subscription. Possibly you've created Azure subscription and Azure DevOps with different users.

Please go and check if you can create an application in AAD.

- If you can, create an empty job instead of wizard.
- Create service connection for Azure.
- Then configure your pipeline.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-create-service-principal-portal

Comment: Is it possible that my university "blocks" my access to the AD? Since I am registered with a mail from them. Therefore I can't access the AD:

{  "shellProps": {    "sessionId": "65XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX005",    "extName": "Microsoft_AAD_IAM",    "contentName": "ActiveDirectoryMenuBlade",    "code": 403  },  "error": {    "message": "Kein Zugriff",    "code": 403  }}

Comment: Can you try creating service principal using below command and share the output. You can take a look at below link if you need more info.  

`az ad sp create-for-rbac --name yourServicePrincipalName --scopes /subscriptions/mySubscriptionID` .  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/create-an-azure-service-principal-azure-cli

Comment: "Directory permission is needed for the current user to register the application. For how to configure, please refer 'https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-create-service-principal-portal'. Original error: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."

Comment: You can try creating new tenant(Azure AD) and migrate your subscription to there. Check out this link https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/transfer-subscription . Or create new subscription using different email. In this way you'll have full control of tenant and subscription. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/?v=exp&adobe_mc_sdid=SDID%3D3FE0BB80A844CA33-6C51EBBC60713EDA%7CMCORGID%3DEA76ADE95776D2EC7F000101%40AdobeOrg%7CTS%3D1647614846&adobe_mc_ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F . If that does now make sense, reach out to me via DM. I can helpwith the process.